HTML and CSS only mask overlay, is it possible?
How to create a CSS-only overlay over images or other HTML elements?
Something like this:

All examples found until now suggest assigning a background and using a mix of either masks or clip-paths over the same element, but I would like to animate the individual elements that are supposed to spotlight the image, I was thinking like this:
<div class="relative-container">
  <img class="full-width-and-height-to-match-container" src="..." />

  <span class="absolute-rounded-mask-big" />
  <span class="absolute-rounded-mask-small" />
  <span class="absolute-rounded-mask-big" />
  <span class="absolute-rounded-mask-medium" />
  ...
</div>

All spans are supposed to be positioned across the relative inner content and display the image underneath, with some animation of x and y transitions that would make for an awesome effect.
I found some examples such as this, (scroll a little to get them) but, as per its example is using JS, something that I would like to avoid

You can use mask with different layers and animate them. Here is a basic example with three circles that you can easily extend to any number.


img {
  /* we define the circle once */
  --g: radial-gradient(#000 70%,#0000 72%) no-repeat;
  /* then use it as many as you want */
  mask:/* position / size */
   var(--g) 50% 50%/55% 55%,
   var(--g) 20% 20%/15% 15%,
   var(--g) 80% 10%/30% 30%;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* update the position and size on hover */
img:hover {
  mask-position: 50% 50%,30% 30%,70% 20%;
  mask-size: 55% 55%,30% 30%,20% 20%;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/300/300">



